# java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand()

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am facing the below mention issue on specific production servers.

```
Fri Feb 26 01:37:59 PST 2016 (T13) (Misc:info): javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
```

nested exception is: 
     java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:909)
     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:897)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:371)

Connection to smtp server logs shows as below

Success Situation:

```
 DEBUG SMTP SENT: DATA
 DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
 DEBUG SMTP SENT: 
 .
 DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 250 2.0.0 u1Q9ZtvF012927 Message accepted for delivery
```

Failure Situation:

```
 Verified Addresses
 testmail@xxx.xx
 DEBUG SMTP SENT: DATA
 DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
 DEBUG SMTP SENT: 
 DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 
 DEBUG SMTP SENT: QUIT
 Fri Feb 26 01:37:59 PST 2016 (T13) (Misc:info): javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
 nested exception is:
```

NOTE : Failed case is not sending "." in the failure situation.

Please help me to identify the root cause of the below failed scenario when 
DEBUG SMTP SENT: will be empty(without .) and  DEBUG SMTP RCVD: will be empty and SMTP connection close throws an exception but actual mail would have sent already.

Comment: You appear to be using a very old version of JavaMail.  If you can, please [upgrade to the latest version](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).  It might help.  But it also might be that your mail server is dropping the connection for some reason.  Your application needs to be prepared to handle these network failures.